# Which IP address in email headers should I ban to block spam from this source?

Tags: email, email-server

I got scam email from `zcsend.net`. This time the sender address is faked. I need to use Fail2Ban to ban messages from the same origin. However, there are many addresses here in the headers. Which one should I ban?

```
Return-Path: <bounce_826278108+a.1ffd60557f594e44_gm1@mail18.psnd.zcsend.net>
Delivered-To: david@example.com
Received: from mail.elcolie.com
    by mail.elcolie.com with LMTP
    id CQu1FWy08mQ8UwEA83h3bQ
    (envelope-from <bounce_826278108+a.1ffd60557f594e44_gm1@mail18.psnd.zcsend.net>)
    for <david@example.com>; Sat, 02 Sep 2023 04:05:00 +0000
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.elcolie.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4F41E835F9
    for <david@example.com>; Sat,  2 Sep 2023 04:05:00 +0000 (UTC)
Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=135.84.81.239; helo=sender-239.fsu3.zcsend.net; envelope-from=bounce_826278108+a.1ffd60557f594e44_gm1@mail18.psnd.zcsend.net; receiver=<UNKNOWN> 
Authentication-Results: mail.elcolie.com; dmarc=none (p=none dis=none) header.from=ahrdigital.com.br
Authentication-Results: mail.elcolie.com;
    dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=mail18.psnd.zcsend.net header.i=@mail18.psnd.zcsend.net header.a=rsa-sha256 header.s=k1 header.b=mfuyyvvw;
    dkim-atps=neutral
Received: from sender-239.fsu3.zcsend.net (sender-239.fsu3.zcsend.net [135.84.81.239])
    by mail.elcolie.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 4A931833FE
    for <david@example.com>; Sat,  2 Sep 2023 04:04:59 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from 172.30.236.109 by sender-239.fsu3.zcsend.net
    with SMTP id 169362748867145850; Fri, 01 Sep 2023 21:04:48 -0700
DKIM-Signature: a=rsa-sha256; b=mfuyyvvwcocf77Gr4eWhg010x1Vak0knteAbKgX+PiHKD2TdnhfbGOZHCItAcuEJSjZN2UGRM/dQMzI9WfytdauyhtACpvDVf+uIn6qRmlNkOn140NbFVuYPDUABu1IBCr6wEwXR2pLevy7Zz1vFWUEuRck+70wzVwMjrj7+yvE=; c=simple/simple; s=k1; d=mail18.psnd.zcsend.net; v=1; bh=LMN9EQQS8smfom6q8kw8Y3zjTellj/Oo1rnIjeRT56c=; h=date:from:to:message-id:subject:mime-version:content-type:list-unsubscribe:list-unsubscribe-post:x-csa-complaints;
Date: Fri, 1 Sep 2023 21:04:48 -0700 (PDT)
From: "Parcel Team" <arthur@ahrdigital.com.br>
To: david@example.com
Message-ID: <zcb.3za2ac949e760ea75599504c608f73642fe6611a47f75af214445fe34174e0169d.1ffd60557f594e44.1693627488661@mail18.psnd.zcsend.net>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?Tm90aWZpY2F0aW9uOsKgIENhc2UgTnVtYmVyICMzMzYxNzI=?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_8830362_773276248.1693627488657"
List-Unsubscribe: <https://vldxa-cmpzourl.maillist-manage.com/ua/optout?od=3za2ac949e760ea75599504c608f73642fe6611a47f75af214445fe34174e0169d&rd=1ffd60557f594e44&sd=1ffd60557f57b0ef&n=11699e4c32dbb4c>,<mailto:leave_826278108+1ffd60557f594e44_1ffd60557f57b0ef@zcsend.net>
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
X-CSA-Complaints: csa-complaints@eco.de
Reply-To: arthur@ahrdigital.com.br
X-JID: 3za2ac949e760ea75599504c608f73642fe6611a47f75af214445fe34174e0169d.1ffd60557f3f24e4
X-campaignid: zohocampaigns.3za2ac949e760ea75599504c608f73642fe6611a47f75af214445fe34174e0169d.zcb.1ffd60557f594e44.11699e4c32dbb4c
X-Zoho-RID: zohocampaigns.3za2ac949e760ea75599504c608f73642fe6611a47f75af214445fe34174e0169d.zcb.1ffd60557f594e44.11699e4c32dbb4c
X-Report-Abuse: <Please send a copy of this message along with header to abuse+3za2ac949e760ea75599504c608f73642fe6611a47f75af214445fe34174e0169d_zcb_1ffd60557f594e44@zohocampaigns.com>, <https://vldxa-cmpzourl.maillist-manage.com/campaigns/ReportAbuse.zc?od=3za2ac949e760ea75599504c608f73642fe6611a47f75af214445fe34174e0169d&rd=1ffd60557f594e44&sd=1ffd60557f57b0ef&n=11699e4c32dbb4c>

------=_Part_8830362_773276248.1693627488657
Content-Type: text/plain;charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I have replace my real email address with `david@example.com`

Since my email server is using https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver
I simply run
`docker exec 2834fea5aa2e setup fail2ban ban 135.84.81.239`

**Questions:**

1. Did I find the correct IP address?
2. Am I blocking it correctly?
3. Am I missing anything?

Comment: But.. that actually is Zoho-managed IP space? If you want to make adjustments for that sender, you would not need to worry about individual addresses, they are all properly named. But you probably do not, they seem to process complaints just fine.

Answer (score 3):

#### Finding the correct IP address

Every *message transfer agent* (MTA) processing the email adds headers at the top of the message, so they are in descending order; the topmost are the newest ones. To find the IP address you should be looking for the `Received` header where your server first accepted the email.

```
Received: from sender-239.fsu3.zcsend.net (sender-239.fsu3.zcsend.net [135.84.81.239])
    by mail.elcolie.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 4A931833FE
    for <david@xxx.com>; Sat,  2 Sep 2023 04:04:59 +0000 (UTC)
```

Here, the first address after the `from` is the `HELO` hostname of the server which should not be trusted. The IP address and the hostname (`PTR`) associated with it are in the brackets.

Hence, `135.84.81.239` is the IP address you were looking for. However, there is more to this...

#### Fail2Ban is not designed for this

Why would you *need* to use Fail2Ban? [Fail2Ban(1)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/fail2ban.1.html) is not for blocking spam, but...

> a  set  of  server  and  client  programs to limit brute force authentication attempts.

#### DNS *Real-time blackhole lists* (RBL)

The IP address in the example, `135.84.81.239`, is currently blacklisted in *real-time blackhole lists* (RBL):

- [SpamCop](https://www.spamcop.net/) Blocking List (`bl.spamcop.net`)
- [JunkEmailFilter.com](https://www.junkemailfilter.com/spam/)'s HostKarma (`hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com`)

Instead of blocking individual IP addresses every time a spam gets through, you could utilize some external services that are already doing that in scale. In addition, most of them will remove the listing when the problem has been resolved.

There are many RBL providers having different kind of listings. You should analyse which of these lists are suitable for your needs. E.g.,

- [Spamhaus](https://www.spamhaus.org/)
- [blocklist.de](https://www.blocklist.de/en/index.html)
- [SpamEatingMonkey](https://spameatingmonkey.com/)
- [SORBS](http://www.sorbs.net/) (Spam and Open Relay Blocking System)
- [Barracuda](https://barracudacentral.org/)
- [dan.me.uk](https://www.dan.me.uk/dnsbl) (specialized in blocking Tor nodes)

#### Configuring RBLs in Postfix

Your headers show you are using Postfix. You can configure, e.g., SpamCop in your `main.cf` by adding a [`reject_rbl_client`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_rbl_client) in [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) where it will be evaluated after full `HELO`, `MAIL FROM` & `RCPT TO`.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    . . .
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    . . .
    permit
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `bl.spamcop.net` does not list 135.84.81.239 IP address.
https://www.spamcop.net/w3m?action=checkblock&ip=135.84.81.239
135.84.81.239 not listed in bl.spamcop.net

Comment: It was listed yesterday. As explained in the answer, those lists dynamically change: listing new IP addresses and delisting others, based on the rules each follow. Your approach would involve making that kind of decisions on your own, based on a tiny dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Blacklisting a single Zoho server won't really do much. They've got a few more.

If you want to ban their servers in total, do it by host domain `zcsend.net` or by *envelope* FROM `@(.*).psnd.zcsend.net>`.

If you don't want to ban them entirely, all you've got left is a complaint.

Of course, you could also try filtering by *header* FROM but that is just too easily spoofed.